# Question about freeing malloc()ed memory in C

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, free, fread

I'm doing the CS50 course (so please don't give me the exact right answer, but point me in the right direction!

I got my program (below) to work (although I'm not sure if I did it 'the right way'); it prints the 8 license plates from plates.txt. However, valgrind still tells me I'm losing some bytes. I know for sure that it has to do with my 'temp' thing allocating memory in the loop. I just don't know how to fix it. If anyone could point me in the right direction, that would be wonderful!

**Valgrind:**

```
==18649== HEAP SUMMARY:
==18649== in use at exit: 49 bytes in 7 blocks
==18649== total heap usage: 10 allocs, 3 frees, 4,624 bytes allocated
==18649==
==18649== 49 bytes in 7 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==18649== at 0x4848899: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==18649== by 0x109257: main (license.c:39)
==18649==
==18649== LEAK SUMMARY:
==18649== definitely lost: 49 bytes in 7 blocks
==18649== indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==18649== possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==18649== still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==18649== suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==18649==
==18649== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==18649== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

**Program code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Check for command line args
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./read infile\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Create buffer to read into
    char buffer[7];

    // Create array to store plate numbers
    char *plates[8];

    // Create a pointer that will later point to a place in memory on the heap for strcpy
    char *temp = NULL;

    FILE *infile = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    if (infile == NULL)
    {
        printf("File not found.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    int idx = 0;

    while (fread(buffer, 1, 7, infile) == 7)
    {
        // Replace '\n' with '\0'
        buffer[6] = '\0';

        // Allocate memory to temporarily store buffer contents
        temp = malloc(sizeof(buffer));

        // Copy buffer contents to temp
        strcpy(temp, buffer);

        // Save plate number in array
        plates[idx] = temp;
        idx++;
    }

    fclose(infile);

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", plates[i]);
    }

    free(temp);

    return 0;
}
```

I fclosed the file and freed my 'temp' location in the heap. However, I malloc() temp multiple times, but I can't free(temp) multiple times?

Comment: Anything allocated with `malloc` must eventually be freed with `free`, which is obviously not the case here.

Comment: Hint: you only free the memory of the last plate.

Comment: Consider this: You call `malloc` in a loop. Shouldn't you call `free` in a loop as well?

Comment: Given that there are apparently only 8 plates and each is of minimal length, do you even need to dynamically allocate memory?

Comment: Don't do `free(temp);`. Hint: Instead free every malloc'ed `temp`.... you did save them in another variable

Comment: OT: `for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)` What will happen if the file only contains 2 plates? Hint: Maybe `idx` could be useful here

Comment: Unrelated to the question, are plate numbers really just 6 characters long?

Comment: Why are you storing the plate numbers in an array before printing them?  That's wasteful, because the program does not do anything that requires it to have all the plate numbers in memory at the same time.  Dynamic allocation would not have any role to play here in the first place if you simply printed the plate numbers immediately after reading them, instead of storing them up in memory and then printing them via a separate loop.

Comment: A common mistake when learning about malloc/free is to forget that you free *the memory*, not the pointer. This program allocates several different memory blocks and only frees the last one.

Comment: But even given that you *are* storing all of them in memory, why are you using dynamic allocation?  You know exactly how many plates you are providing for, and how much space you are providing for them, and the total space is very small.  None of the reasons for dynamic allocation are present here.

Comment: OT: If you want dynamic allocation for the individual plate then you should also do dynamic allocation for this `char *plates[8];` so that you can handle any number of plates.

Comment: Please don't add "solved" in your title. Instead, do what you already did: upvote and accept the answer that helps you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to free all allocated pointers.

```
for(i = 0; i < idx; i++) 
   free(plates[i]);
```

You also can very easily fo beyond your array bounds as you do not check the index

```
 while (idx < 8 && fread(buffer, 1, 7, infile) == 7)
```

Printing is also wrong as you assume that you have read all 8 chunks.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < idx; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", plates[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

`free(temp);` is wrong, it just deletes the last item allocated.

Since you called `malloc` in a loop, you'll also have to call `free` in a loop. The rule of thumb is that every `malloc`call must be matched by a `free`call.

So you have to make a `for` loop iterating across `char *plates[8];` and `free` everything that each `plates` pointer points at.